# Query statement consume quite long time on execution on oracle

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, sql-tuning

I got task to improve existing code / query from my company,

Database version

```
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bi
PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.4.0 - Production
"CORE   10.2.0.4.0  Production"
TNS for IBM/AIX RISC System/6000: Version 10.2.0.4.0 - Productio
NLSRTL Version 10.2.0.4.0 - Production
```

Here's the problem- when below code is executed, the time taken to finish the job is more than 4 hours, something around 7 to 8 hours.

[image]

*395 row data within   3  hours    37  minutes*

```
  SELECT DISTINCT GROUP_DIST_NUMBER, BEGIN_DATE, PRICE_DROP_DATE
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
                 G.GROUP_DIST_NUMBER,
                 TO_DATE (:B2, 'DD-MON-YYYY') BEGIN_DATE,
                 TO_DATE (:B2, 'DD-MON-YYYY') PRICE_DROP_DATE
            FROM POS_DISTI_GROUP G,
                 POS_CUST_XREF M,
                 S_CPT_SEQ_NO C,
                 PP_STD_PRICE P,
                 S_CPT_AUDIT A,
                 RPT_PRODUCT_VALUE_LEVEL L
           WHERE     G.END_DATE > TO_DATE (:B2, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
                 AND G.GROUP_DIST_NUMBER = M.DIST_NUMBER
                 AND M.SG_BILL_TO_CUST_NO = A.BILL_TO_CUST_NO
                 AND A.START_DATE <= TO_DATE (:B2, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
                 AND A.END_DATE >= TO_DATE (:B2, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
                 AND L.PROD_VALUE = P.PROD_VALUE
                 AND L.PROD_LEVEL = P.PROD_LEVEL
                 AND C.CPT_PRICE_CODE IN
                        (SELECT /*+ PRECOMPUTE_SUBQUERY */
                                DISTINCT C1.CPT_PRICE_CODE
                           FROM PP_STD_PRICE P1,
                                S_CPT_PRICE_CODE C1,
                                S_CPT_SEQ_NO S1
                          WHERE     P1.STDP_ID = :B1
                                AND C1.CPT_PRICE_CAT LIKE 'NB%'
                                AND C1.CPT_PRICE_CODE = S1.CPT_PRICE_CODE
                                AND S1.PRICE_PROTECTABLE = 'Y')
                 AND C.CPT_PRICE_CODE = P.CUST_PRICE_TYPE
                 AND P.STDP_ID = :B1
                 AND A.CUST_PRICE_TYPE = C.CPT_BILL_CODE
                 AND M.ACTIVE_IND != 'N'
                 AND (M.CATEGORY_TYPE LIKE 'DIRECT%' OR M.INDIRECT_DISTI = 'Y')
                 AND TRUNC (M.ARCHIVE_DATE) > TRUNC (SYSDATE)
          UNION
            SELECT G.GROUP_DIST_NUMBER,
                   P.BEGIN_DATE,
                   MIN (INVT.PRICE_DROP_DATE) PRICE_DROP_DATE
              FROM POS_DISTI_GROUP G,
                   POS_CUST_XREF M,
                   PP_DEBIT_AUTHORIZATION P,
                   RPT_PRODUCT_VALUE_LEVEL L,
                   POS_PP_INVENTORY INVT
             WHERE     G.END_DATE > TO_DATE (:B2, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
                   AND G.GROUP_DIST_NUMBER = M.DIST_NUMBER
                   AND M.ACTIVE_IND != 'N'
                   AND (M.CATEGORY_TYPE LIKE 'DIRECT%' OR M.INDIRECT_DISTI = 'Y')
                   AND G.DIST_NUMBER = P.DIST_NUMBER
                   AND L.PROD_VALUE = P.PROD_VALUE
                   AND L.PROD_LEVEL = P.PROD_LEVEL
                   AND P.BEGIN_DATE >= TO_DATE (:B2, 'DD-MON-YYYY') - 6
                   AND P.BEGIN_DATE <= TO_DATE (:B2, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
                   AND INVT.DIST_NUMBER = G.GROUP_DIST_NUMBER
                   AND INVT.STMODEL = L.MOD_DESC
                   AND INVT.PPCF_SHOW_DATE = P.BEGIN_DATE
                   AND P.PRICE_TYPE = 'I'
                   AND (   P.POS_PROCESSED_FLAG IS NULL
                        OR P.POS_PROCESSED_FLAG != 'C')
                   AND P.POS_PP_FLAG = 'Y'
                   AND TRUNC (M.ARCHIVE_DATE) > TRUNC (SYSDATE)
          GROUP BY G.GROUP_DIST_NUMBER, P.BEGIN_DATE)
ORDER BY GROUP_DIST_NUMBER;
```

I have no idea how to tune this query statement to improve the performance and make it execute faster

here the EXPLAIN PLAN

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                 | Name                        | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Pstart| Pstop |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                          |                             |   101 |  2525 |       | 24156  (10)|       |       |
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY                            |                             |   101 |  2525 |       | 24156  (10)|       |       |
|   2 |   VIEW                                    |                             |   101 |  2525 |       | 24155  (10)|       |       |
|   3 |    SORT UNIQUE                            |                             |   101 | 17691 |       | 24155  (75)|       |       |
|   4 |     UNION-ALL                             |                             |       |       |       |            |       |       |
|*  5 |      HASH JOIN                            |                             |    10M|  1680M|       |  6446   (5)|       |       |
|*  6 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL                   | S_CPT_SEQ_NO                |   651 |  5208 |       |     5   (0)|       |       |
|*  7 |       HASH JOIN                           |                             |  2383K|   379M|       |  6318   (3)|       |       |
|*  8 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL                  | POS_DISTI_GROUP             |   100 |  1800 |       |     5   (0)|       |       |
|*  9 |        HASH JOIN                          |                             |  2396K|   340M|  4320K|  6283   (3)|       |       |
|  10 |         VIEW                              | RPT_PRODUCT_VALUE_LEVEL     |   138K|  2697K|       |  1905   (3)|       |       |
|  11 |          UNION-ALL                        |                             |       |       |       |            |       |       |
|* 12 |           HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER           |                             | 13965 |   627K|       |    91   (5)|       |       |
|  13 |            INDEX FULL SCAN                | PK_SEAEGO_PRODUCT_HIERARCHY |   298 |  4172 |       |     1   (0)|       |       |
|* 14 |            HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER          |                             | 13965 |   436K|       |    89   (4)|       |       |
|  15 |             INDEX FULL SCAN               | PK_S_CAP_GROUP              |     2 |     8 |       |     1   (0)|       |       |
|  16 |             TABLE ACCESS FULL             | SMA_STMODEL                 | 13965 |   381K|       |    87   (3)|       |       |
|* 17 |           HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER           |                             | 14175 |  1065K|       |   158   (5)|       |       |
|  18 |            INDEX FAST FULL SCAN           | PK_S_FAMILY                 |  1366 |  5464 |       |     2   (0)|       |       |
|* 19 |            HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER          |                             | 14175 |  1010K|       |   156   (5)|       |       |
|  20 |             INDEX FULL SCAN               | PK_F_MODPRODMGR             |    22 |    88 |       |     1   (0)|       |       |
|* 21 |             HASH JOIN                     |                             | 14175 |   955K|       |   154   (4)|       |       |
|  22 |              TABLE ACCESS FULL            | SMA_PRODUCTMODEL            | 14132 |   317K|       |    62   (2)|       |       |
|* 23 |              HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER        |                             | 13965 |   627K|       |    91   (5)|       |       |
|  24 |               INDEX FULL SCAN             | PK_SEAEGO_PRODUCT_HIERARCHY |   298 |  4172 |       |     1   (0)|       |       |
|* 25 |               HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER       |                             | 13965 |   436K|       |    89   (4)|       |       |
|  26 |                INDEX FULL SCAN            | PK_S_CAP_GROUP              |     2 |     8 |       |     1   (0)|       |       |
|  27 |                TABLE ACCESS FULL          | SMA_STMODEL                 | 13965 |   381K|       |    87   (3)|       |       |
|  28 |           MAT_VIEW ACCESS FULL            | RPT_PROD_MV                 |   109K|  1288K|       |  1656   (3)|       |       |
|* 29 |         HASH JOIN                         |                             |   141K|    17M|       |  3191   (3)|       |       |
|* 30 |          INDEX RANGE SCAN                 | UK_PP_STD_PRICE_STDP_ID     |  4128 |   108K|       |    23   (0)|       |       |
|* 31 |          HASH JOIN                        |                             |  5341 |   532K|       |  3165   (3)|       |       |
|* 32 |           TABLE ACCESS FULL               | POS_CUST_XREF               |    54 |  2268 |       |    25   (4)|       |       |
|* 33 |           HASH JOIN                       |                             |   193K|    11M|       |  3137   (3)|       |       |
|* 34 |            TABLE ACCESS FULL              | S_CPT_AUDIT                 |    68 |  2108 |       |    76   (4)|       |       |
|* 35 |            HASH JOIN                      |                             |   745K|    20M|       |  3052   (2)|       |       |
|  36 |             TABLE ACCESS FULL             | S_CPT_SEQ_NO                |  1301 | 16913 |       |     5   (0)|       |       |
|  37 |             MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN          |                             | 88205 |  1378K|       |  3037   (2)|       |       |
|* 38 |              INDEX RANGE SCAN             | UK_PP_STD_PRICE_STDP_ID     |  4128 | 20640 |       |    23   (0)|       |       |
|  39 |              BUFFER SORT                  |                             |    21 |   231 |       |  3014   (2)|       |       |
|* 40 |               TABLE ACCESS FULL           | S_CPT_PRICE_CODE            |    21 |   231 |       |     1   (0)|       |       |
|  41 |      HASH GROUP BY                        |                             |     1 |   191 |       | 16421   (5)|       |       |
|* 42 |       FILTER                              |                             |       |       |       |            |       |       |
|  43 |        NESTED LOOPS                       |                             |     1 |   191 |       | 16419   (5)|       |       |
|* 44 |         HASH JOIN                         |                             |     7 |  1176 |       | 16370   (5)|       |       |
|* 45 |          HASH JOIN                        |                             |    74 |  8584 |       |  4790   (3)|       |       |
|* 46 |           HASH JOIN                       |                             |    60 |  3780 |       |    31   (7)|       |       |
|* 47 |            TABLE ACCESS FULL              | POS_CUST_XREF               |    60 |  2100 |       |    25   (4)|       |       |
|* 48 |            TABLE ACCESS FULL              | POS_DISTI_GROUP             |   100 |  2800 |       |     5   (0)|       |       |
|* 49 |           TABLE ACCESS FULL               | PP_DEBIT_AUTHORIZATION      |   345 | 18285 |       |  4759   (3)|       |       |
|  50 |          PARTITION RANGE ALL              |                             | 18192 |   923K|       | 11579   (6)|     1 |    33 |
|* 51 |           INDEX FAST FULL SCAN            | POS_PP_INVENTORY_PK         | 18192 |   923K|       | 11579   (6)|     1 |    33 |
|* 52 |         VIEW                              | RPT_PRODUCT_VALUE_LEVEL     |     1 |    23 |       |     7   (0)|       |       |
|  53 |          UNION ALL PUSHED PREDICATE       |                             |       |       |       |            |       |       |
|* 54 |           FILTER                          |                             |       |       |       |            |       |       |
|  55 |            NESTED LOOPS OUTER             |                             |     1 |    46 |       |     2   (0)|       |       |
|  56 |             NESTED LOOPS OUTER            |                             |     1 |    42 |       |     2   (0)|       |       |
|  57 |              TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | SMA_STMODEL                 |     1 |    28 |       |     2   (0)|       |       |
|* 58 |               INDEX UNIQUE SCAN           | PK_SMA_STMODEL              |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)|       |       |
|* 59 |              INDEX UNIQUE SCAN            | PK_SEAEGO_PRODUCT_HIERARCHY |   298 |  4172 |       |     0   (0)|       |       |
|* 60 |             INDEX UNIQUE SCAN             | PK_S_CAP_GROUP              |     2 |     8 |       |     0   (0)|       |       |
|  61 |           NESTED LOOPS OUTER              |                             |     1 |    77 |       |     3   (0)|       |       |
|  62 |            NESTED LOOPS OUTER             |                             |     1 |    73 |       |     3   (0)|       |       |
|  63 |             NESTED LOOPS OUTER            |                             |     1 |    69 |       |     3   (0)|       |       |
|  64 |              NESTED LOOPS OUTER           |                             |     1 |    65 |       |     3   (0)|       |       |
|  65 |               NESTED LOOPS                |                             |     1 |    51 |       |     3   (0)|       |       |
|* 66 |                TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| SMA_PRODUCTMODEL            |     1 |    23 |       |     2   (0)|       |       |
|* 67 |                 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | PK_SMA_PRODUCTMODEL         |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)|       |       |
|  68 |                TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| SMA_STMODEL                 |     1 |    28 |       |     1   (0)|       |       |
|* 69 |                 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | PK_SMA_STMODEL              |     1 |       |       |     0   (0)|       |       |
|* 70 |               INDEX UNIQUE SCAN           | PK_SEAEGO_PRODUCT_HIERARCHY |   298 |  4172 |       |     0   (0)|       |       |
|* 71 |              INDEX UNIQUE SCAN            | PK_S_FAMILY                 |  1366 |  5464 |       |     0   (0)|       |       |
|* 72 |             INDEX UNIQUE SCAN             | PK_S_CAP_GROUP              |     2 |     8 |       |     0   (0)|       |       |
|* 73 |            INDEX UNIQUE SCAN              | PK_F_MODPRODMGR             |    22 |    88 |       |     0   (0)|       |       |
|* 74 |           MAT_VIEW ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | RPT_PROD_MV                 |     1 |    24 |       |     2   (0)|       |       |
|* 75 |            INDEX UNIQUE SCAN              | IDX_RPT_PROD_MV_PROD_NO     |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)|       |       |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   5 - access("C1"."CPT_PRICE_CODE"="S1"."CPT_PRICE_CODE")
   6 - filter("S1"."PRICE_PROTECTABLE"='Y')
   7 - access("G"."GROUP_DIST_NUMBER"="M"."DIST_NUMBER")
   8 - filter("G"."END_DATE">TO_DATE(:B2,'DD-MON-YYYY'))
   9 - access("L"."PROD_VALUE"="P"."PROD_VALUE" AND "L"."PROD_LEVEL"="P"."PROD_LEVEL")
  12 - access("ST"."MARKETING_NAME"="PH"."MARKETING_NAME"(+))
  14 - access("ST"."MOD_CAPACITY_FORMATTED"="SCG"."MOD_CAPACITY_FORMATTED"(+))
  17 - access("SF"."FAMILY"(+)=SUBSTRB("PM"."MODEL",1,3))
  19 - access("PM"."DESIGN_APPLICATION"="DA"."DESIGN_APPLICATION"(+))
  21 - access("PM"."MOD_DESC"="ST"."MOD_DESC")
  23 - access("ST"."MARKETING_NAME"="PH"."MARKETING_NAME"(+))
  25 - access("ST"."MOD_CAPACITY_FORMATTED"="SCG"."MOD_CAPACITY_FORMATTED"(+))
  29 - access("C"."CPT_PRICE_CODE"="P"."CUST_PRICE_TYPE")
  30 - access("P"."STDP_ID"=TO_NUMBER(:B1))
  31 - access("M"."SG_BILL_TO_CUST_NO"="A"."BILL_TO_CUST_NO")
  32 - filter("M"."SG_BILL_TO_CUST_NO" IS NOT NULL AND ("M"."INDIRECT_DISTI"='Y' OR "M"."CATEGORY_TYPE" LIKE 'DIRECT%') AND 
              "M"."ACTIVE_IND"<>'N' AND TRUNC(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("M"."ARCHIVE_DATE"))>TRUNC(SYSDATE@!))
  33 - access("A"."CUST_PRICE_TYPE"="C"."CPT_BILL_CODE")
  34 - filter("A"."START_DATE"<=TO_DATE(:B2,'DD-MON-YYYY') AND "A"."END_DATE">=TO_DATE(:B2,'DD-MON-YYYY'))
  35 - access("C"."CPT_PRICE_CODE"="C1"."CPT_PRICE_CODE")
  38 - access("P1"."STDP_ID"=TO_NUMBER(:B1))
  40 - filter("C1"."CPT_PRICE_CAT" LIKE 'NB%')
  42 - filter(TO_DATE(:B2,'DD-MON-YYYY')-6<=TO_DATE(:B2,'DD-MON-YYYY'))
  44 - access("INVT"."DIST_NUMBER"="G"."GROUP_DIST_NUMBER" AND "INVT"."PPCF_SHOW_DATE"="P"."BEGIN_DATE")
  45 - access("G"."DIST_NUMBER"="P"."DIST_NUMBER")
  46 - access("G"."GROUP_DIST_NUMBER"="M"."DIST_NUMBER")
  47 - filter(("M"."INDIRECT_DISTI"='Y' OR "M"."CATEGORY_TYPE" LIKE 'DIRECT%') AND "M"."ACTIVE_IND"<>'N' AND 
              TRUNC(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("M"."ARCHIVE_DATE"))>TRUNC(SYSDATE@!))
  48 - filter("G"."END_DATE">TO_DATE(:B2,'DD-MON-YYYY'))
  49 - filter("P"."PRICE_TYPE"='I' AND "P"."POS_PP_FLAG"='Y' AND ("P"."POS_PROCESSED_FLAG"<>'C' OR "P"."POS_PROCESSED_FLAG" 
              IS NULL) AND "P"."BEGIN_DATE"<=TO_DATE(:B2,'DD-MON-YYYY') AND "P"."BEGIN_DATE">=TO_DATE(:B2,'DD-MON-YYYY')-6)
  51 - filter("INVT"."PPCF_SHOW_DATE"<=TO_DATE(:B2,'DD-MON-YYYY') AND "INVT"."PPCF_SHOW_DATE">=TO_DATE(:B2,'DD-MON-YYYY')-6)
  52 - filter("L"."PROD_LEVEL"="P"."PROD_LEVEL")
  54 - filter("P"."PROD_VALUE"="INVT"."STMODEL")
  58 - access("ST"."MOD_DESC"="P"."PROD_VALUE")
  59 - access("ST"."MARKETING_NAME"="PH"."MARKETING_NAME"(+))
  60 - access("ST"."MOD_CAPACITY_FORMATTED"="SCG"."MOD_CAPACITY_FORMATTED"(+))
  66 - filter("PM"."MOD_DESC"="INVT"."STMODEL")
  67 - access("PM"."MODEL"="P"."PROD_VALUE")
  69 - access("ST"."MOD_DESC"="INVT"."STMODEL")
  70 - access("ST"."MARKETING_NAME"="PH"."MARKETING_NAME"(+))
  71 - access("SF"."FAMILY"(+)=SUBSTRB("PM"."MODEL",1,3))
  72 - access("ST"."MOD_CAPACITY_FORMATTED"="SCG"."MOD_CAPACITY_FORMATTED"(+))
  73 - access("PM"."DESIGN_APPLICATION"="DA"."DESIGN_APPLICATION"(+))
  74 - filter("MOD_DESC"="INVT"."STMODEL")
  75 - access("PROD_NO"="P"."PROD_VALUE")

Note
-----
   - 'PLAN_TABLE' is old version
```

and the statistic of rows count for table

```
    TABLE_Name              NUM_ROWS
    -----------             ---------
    POS_DISTI_GROUP          2009 
    POS_CUST_XREF            2801
    S_CPT_SEQ_NO             1301
    PP_STD_PRICE             2658450
    S_CPT_AUDIT            27200
    PP_DEBIT_AUTHORIZATION   1199420
    POS_PP_INVENTORY     7276850
    PP_STD_PRICE             2658450
    S_CPT_PRICE_CODE     192
    S_CPT_SEQ_NO             1301
    SMA_STMODEL          13965
    RPT_PROD_MV          109980
```

create table statement. [CLICK HERE](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_na4elV6tk0AbTXV1NNAnPurle3jSj5MwELuGvd_Y_k/edit?usp=sharing)

Table Description. [CLICK HERE](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1en6YDg0ASBvHu-Ewm1zmZZr3mJ-a4RyKIbz3KsJ3de0/edit?usp=sharing)

Retrieve EXPLAIN PLAN with rerun gather_plan_statistics as @jonearles suggest. [CLICK HERE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B--wuJRWadaQekZ3eURPWVlDWTA/edit?usp=sharing)

*link from google doc

Comment: Can you please post the Explain Plan output? See here for how to use it- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28274/ex_plan.htm

Comment: Start with `EXPLAIN PLAN` (reference [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/ex_plan.htm)) and look at adding appropriate indexes

Comment: thanks @Rachcha, i will go through with explain plan

Comment: Once you get the EXPLAIN PLAN output, post it here (by editing the question) so that we know exactly where the query is taking long for. Meanwhile, I would suggest you remove all the `DISTINCT` you have used, as it is not really necessary as there is already a `UNION` and  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: already edit the post with EXPLAIN PLAN @Rachcha

Comment: ok i will run the query for count now and edit the post, this program using java EE 1.4 and above query came from package procedure @realspirituals

Comment: What indications are there that this query should execute faster than it currently does?

Comment: What about indexes and partitions? Could you please post create table statements?

Comment: lol... I see range partition in your query. It means that your table POS_PP_INVENTORY is created on partition. Confirm them with indexes and create table statments.

Comment: @realspirituals , edit post by update create table statement

Comment: @DavidAldridge ,i'm newbie in sql oracle that why i ask here, because this is first time for me to deal with the performance issues

Comment: @DavidAldridge. Many things I note here.. This is in my opinion... Too many suqueries, usage of WHERE clause, partition tables without using them, Distinct, order by, they all may cause issues. Definitely can rewrite

Comment: @user2982040 you missed out the table RPT_STMODEL_DETAIL and RPT_PRODUCT_DETAIL;

Comment: This looks like a simple case of the optimizer using NESTED LOOPs instead of a HASH JOIN, becaue it is underestimating the number of ROWS.  Any explain plan that uses large tables but has ROWS=1 is suspect.  Try re-running with the hint `/*+ gather_plan_statistics */` and then retrieve the explain plan with `dbms_xplan.display_cursor(format=>'allstats')`.  Chances are there will be many lines where the Estimated Rows are orders of magnitude lower than the Actual Rows.  If that's true, you can use things like dynamic sampling, extended statistics, or a use_hash hint to fix the plan.

Comment: @jonearles, from my reading about nested loops use for the small amount of rows and hash join for the large amount of rows, instead using nested loop, can we use merger join?

Answer (score 4):

**The problem**

Aggregation is happening too late in the execution plan.  Plan IDs 4 and 5 generate 13 *billion* rows and account for 95% of the execution time.  Oracle incorrectly believes the number of rows will be smaller, and that earlier aggregations should be merged together.

Plan IDs 6 through 40 represent the first half of the inline view, before the `UNION`.  That part of the query has two `DISTINCT`s, yet there are no types of aggregation operations for that part of the execution plan.  Oracle incorrectly thinks it's better to join everything first and perform one `SORT UNIQUE`, instead of performing multiple `SORT UNIQUE` or `HASH GROUP BY` and combining the results.

**Reproduce the problem**

Fully reproducing this problem without a full export is almost impossible.  Even though it's only a moderately complicated SQL statement there are thousands of variables involved.  The code below only demonstrates how Oracle can incorrectly merge aggregation operations.

First, create two simple tables.  Each has 100K rows.  TEST1 has numbers from 1 to 100000.  TEST2 contains 100000 rows, but only one distinct number.  To artificially make a bad plan, statistics are gathered too soon on TEST2.  The optimizer *thinks* that TEST2 only has one row but it really has 100000.

```
drop table test1 purge;
drop table test2 purge;

create table test1(a number);
create table test2(a number);

insert into test1 select level from dual connect by level <= 100000;
insert into test2 values (1);
commit;

begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'test1');
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'test2');
end;
/

insert into test2 select 1 from dual connect by level <= 100000;
commit;
```

The sample query below retrieves all distinct TEST1.A where A is also in distinct TEST2.A.

By default, using the artificially bad statistics, Oracle joins the tables first and then performs the `HASH GROUP BY` and `HASH UNIQUE`.  This is a bad plan, it joins all
100K values from TEST2.  It would be better to perform the `HASH GROUP BY` first and then only join 1 row from that table.

```
explain plan for
select distinct a from test1 where a in (select a from test2 group by a);

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display(format => 'outline'));

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |       |     1 |     8 |    79   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  HASH UNIQUE         |       |     1 |     8 |    79   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   HASH GROUP BY      |       |     1 |     8 |    79   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    HASH JOIN         |       |     1 |     8 |    79   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| TEST2 |     1 |     3 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| TEST1 |   100K|   488K|    76   (2)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Potential Solution #1: Hints**

Unfortunately there are no official hints to control when and where sorting and grouping happen.  By playing around with the `outline` format option I was able to find a few potentially helpful hints: `USE_HASH_AGGREGATION`, `OUTLINE_LEAF`, and `PLACE_DISTINCT`.  (These hints are really tricky - the reason I used a `group by` instead of another `distinct` in my sample is because I had so much trouble with the `PLACE_DISTINCT` hint!)

Using these undocumented hints can build a better plan.  The results from TEST2 go through a `HASH GROUP BY` right away, as they should.  This is similar to the plan that would be produced if the statistics were accurate.

```
explain plan for
select /*+ USE_HASH_AGGREGATION(@"SEL$5DA710D3") OUTLINE_LEAF(@"SEL$683B0107") */
distinct a from test1 where a in (select a from test2 group by a);

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display(format => 'outline alias'));

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation             | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT      |          |     1 |     8 |    79   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  HASH UNIQUE          |          |     1 |     8 |    79   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN SEMI      |          |     1 |     8 |    79   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    VIEW               | VW_NSO_1 |     1 |     3 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     HASH GROUP BY     |          |     1 |     3 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL| TEST2    |     1 |     3 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   6 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL  | TEST1    |   100K|   488K|    76   (2)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Potential Solution #2: Force a plan with ROWNUM.**

A much simpler and safer version of the above is to use `ROWNUM`.  `ROWNUM` is a pseudocolumn that represents the order of the rows returned.  When there is a `ROWNUM` Oracle cannot move the `distinct` and `group by` because it would affect that order.

Unfortunately, this trick requires extra code and generates extra steps in the plan.  Those extra steps are mostly just passing data through and shouldn't slow things done much.

```
explain plan for
select distinct a from test1 where a in
(
    --Extra level only because we only want to project one column.
    --It's syntactically required, but the optimizer throws out this inline view.
    select a
    from
    (
        --The ROWNUM forces everything in this inline view to happen separately.
        select a, rownum
        from
        (
            select a from test2 group by a
        )
    )
);

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display(format => 'outline alias'));

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation               | Name  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT        |       |     1 |     8 |    79   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  HASH UNIQUE            |       |     1 |     8 |    79   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN SEMI        |       |     1 |     8 |    79   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    VIEW                 |       |     1 |     3 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     COUNT               |       |       |       |            |          |
|   5 |      VIEW               |       |     1 |     3 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   6 |       HASH GROUP BY     |       |     1 |     3 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   7 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL| TEST2 |     1 |     3 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   8 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL    | TEST1 |   100K|   488K|    76   (2)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Potential Solution #3: Fix cardinality estimates and hope for the best.**

If the estimated number of rows is accurate the plan is almost always good.  When the row estimates are far off, find the first part of the execution plan where the cardinality is wrong.  For this plan, it appears to be plan ID 36.  E-Rows and A-Rows are off by an order of magnitude:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                 | Name                        | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers | Reads  |  OMem |  1Mem |  O/1/M   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
|* 36 |             TABLE ACCESS FULL             | POS_CUST_XREF               |      1 |     54 |    579 |00:00:00.01 |     131 |      0 |       |       |          |
```

Step 36 has a complex predicate that involves SYSDATE.

```
  36 - filter(("M"."SG_BILL_TO_CUST_NO" IS NOT NULL AND ("M"."INDIRECT_DISTI"='Y' OR "M"."CATEGORY_TYPE" LIKE 'DIRECT%') AND "M"."ACTIVE_IND"<>'N' AND
              TRUNC(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("M"."ARCHIVE_DATE"))>TRUNC(SYSDATE@!)))
```

Even with up-to-date statistics that condition is going to be difficult to predict.  Dynamic sampling may help.  Try re-running the query with a top-level hint like this:

```
SELECT /*+ dynamic_sampling(6) */ ...
```

Fixing those early discrepancies will usually fix other problems later in the plan.  This example is only one possible source of cardinality mismatches.  Other tricks may be necessary to improve other cardinality estimates.  This can be a very difficult method but it can pay off in multiple ways.

**Red Herrings**

There are many potential improvements to any moderately complicated SQL statement.  There are several good ideas in the comments and answers.  But when tuning it is always imperative to focus on what is slowest, not what is easiest to fix.  It sounds obvious, but it's a very easy trap to fall into.  That's why I asked you to use `/*+ gather_plan_statistics*/`, and that's why my answer only focuses on the parts of the plan with a large actual time.

For example, in my earlier comment I suggested looking at the `NESTED LOOPS` where ROWS=1.  Now that we have the actual time we know that suggestion is not helpful.  (Although in general you should still be skeptical of a plan with large tables but ROWS=1.)

Answer (score 0):

just guess, but look like your statement not using index on archive_date column
try to use

```
AND M.ARCHIVE_DATE > TRUNC (SYSDATE) + 1 - 1/24/60/60
```

instead of

```
AND TRUNC (M.ARCHIVE_DATE) > TRUNC (SYSDATE)
```

also you should post all tables description into question

```
SELECT                       /*+ PARALLEL (P,4) PARALLEL (L,4)*/
            DISTINCT
            G.GROUP_DIST_NUMBER,
            TO_DATE ( :B2,
                    'DD-MON-YYYY' )
                BEGIN_DATE,
            TO_DATE ( :B2,
                    'DD-MON-YYYY' )
                PRICE_DROP_DATE
       FROM
            POS_DISTI_GROUP G,
            POS_CUST_XREF M,
            S_CPT_SEQ_NO C,
            PP_STD_PRICE P,
            S_CPT_AUDIT A,
            RPT_PRODUCT_VALUE_LEVEL L
       WHERE 1=0 -- switched off
                G.END_DATE > TO_DATE ( :B2,
                                  'DD-MON-YYYY' )
            AND G.GROUP_DIST_NUMBER = M.DIST_NUMBER
            AND M.SG_BILL_TO_CUST_NO = A.BILL_TO_CUST_NO
            AND A.START_DATE <= TO_DATE ( :B2,
                                    'DD-MON-YYYY' )
            AND A.END_DATE >= TO_DATE ( :B2,
                                   'DD-MON-YYYY' )
            AND L.PROD_VALUE = P.PROD_VALUE
            AND L.PROD_LEVEL = P.PROD_LEVEL
            AND C.CPT_PRICE_CODE IN
                    (SELECT                    /*+  PARALLEL (P1,4)*/
                          DISTINCT C1.CPT_PRICE_CODE
                    FROM
                          PP_STD_PRICE P1,
                          S_CPT_PRICE_CODE C1,
                          S_CPT_SEQ_NO S1
                    WHERE
                             P1.STDP_ID = :B1
                          AND C1.CPT_PRICE_CAT LIKE 'NB%'
                          AND C1.CPT_PRICE_CODE = S1.CPT_PRICE_CODE
                          AND S1.PRICE_PROTECTABLE = 'Y')
            AND C.CPT_PRICE_CODE = P.CUST_PRICE_TYPE
            AND P.STDP_ID = :B1
            AND A.CUST_PRICE_TYPE = C.CPT_BILL_CODE
            AND M.ACTIVE_IND != 'N'
            AND ( M.CATEGORY_TYPE LIKE 'DIRECT%'
                OR M.INDIRECT_DISTI = 'Y' )
            AND TRUNC ( M.ARCHIVE_DATE ) > TRUNC ( SYSDATE )
       UNION
       SELECT                      /*+  PARALLEL (P,4) PARALLEL (L,4) */
            G.GROUP_DIST_NUMBER,
            P.BEGIN_DATE,
            MIN ( INVT.PRICE_DROP_DATE ) PRICE_DROP_DATE
       FROM
            POS_DISTI_GROUP G,
            POS_CUST_XREF M,
            PP_DEBIT_AUTHORIZATION P,
            RPT_PRODUCT_VALUE_LEVEL L,
            POS_PP_INVENTORY PARTITION ("F2011_Q2") INVT
       WHERE 1=0 -- switched off
                G.END_DATE > TO_DATE ( :B2,
                                  'DD-MON-YYYY' )
            AND G.GROUP_DIST_NUMBER = M.DIST_NUMBER
            AND M.ACTIVE_IND != 'N'
            AND ( M.CATEGORY_TYPE LIKE 'DIRECT%'
                OR M.INDIRECT_DISTI = 'Y' )
            AND G.DIST_NUMBER = P.DIST_NUMBER
            AND L.PROD_VALUE = P.PROD_VALUE
            AND L.PROD_LEVEL = P.PROD_LEVEL
            AND P.BEGIN_DATE >= TO_DATE ( :B2,
                                    'DD-MON-YYYY' )
                            - 6
            AND P.BEGIN_DATE <= TO_DATE ( :B2,
                                    'DD-MON-YYYY' )
            AND INVT.DIST_NUMBER = G.GROUP_DIST_NUMBER
            AND INVT.STMODEL = L.MOD_DESC
            AND INVT.PPCF_SHOW_DATE = P.BEGIN_DATE
            AND P.PRICE_TYPE = 'I'
            AND ( P.POS_PROCESSED_FLAG IS NULL
                OR P.POS_PROCESSED_FLAG != 'C' )
            AND P.POS_PP_FLAG = 'Y'
            AND TRUNC ( M.ARCHIVE_DATE ) > TRUNC ( SYSDATE )
       GROUP BY
            G.GROUP_DIST_NUMBER,
            P.BEGIN_DATE
```

**Result From OP**:

After try to switch off and on here there result
1. Switch off 1st where condition
[image: Switch off 1st where condition]

2.Switch off 2nd where condition
[image: Switch off 2nd where condition]

3.Switch off 3rd where condition , it started to long running, so i guess the select query at 2nd condition taken long time on execution
[image: Switch off 3rd where condition]

Comment: I agree that Oracle date comparisons works, but no index cannot be used because it is invalidated with the trunc function (unless you create a function-based index on trunc(date). But your solution might produce wrong result set. Try to support your answer

Comment: yes you right look like statement try to take archived_date in future I change my answer, thank you

Comment: Let OP get back on table stats.. my suspect is on range partitions which might be on date... Also ORDER BY, DISTINCT, lack  of parallel hints... zzzz

Comment: @Galbarad i try to run by edit what you mention above, and remove all DISTINCT keyword, but still not help

Comment: @user2982040 what indexes you have on tables: PP_STD_PRICE PP_DEBIT_AUTHORIZATION POS_PP_INVENTORY ?

Comment: @user2982040 try switch off one of union select with 1=0 and check with select take more time (maybe one of them fast and you need optimize only one)

Comment: @Galbarad ok i will try run with union all, what you mean by indexes on that table? how to switch off with select 1 = 0?

Comment: @Galbarad i try with the union all, it faster, only within 90 second, but it produce result 57098 rows, instead of actual result before changes is 395 rows.

Comment: @user2982040 I give example in my answer. try switch on one of two select and you found most slow statement

Answer (score 0):

Before rewriting the query, could you please reply with plan and run time for this query?

**Follow Up:**

1. Adding Parallel hint
2. Adding partition clause in select

The precompute_subquery hint will take subquery text out of the subquery section, fire it separately (before running main query) in a recursive call context, fetch the results and pass these to main query "filter" condition as a list of OR conditions. This is called subquery unfolding I think and it's different from the query block unparsing which is used for distributed queries. I've seen it used in OLAP queries.

As this is an undocumented hint, it should not be used by developers! The subquery is actually executed during soft parsing time, thus multiple executions of the same child cursor may potentially return wrong results if resultset of the subquery changes (unless Oracle always forces another full parse of these cursors somehow - in which case you can end up with library cache/shared pool latch contention if misusing this feature). So I removed it and used parallel for huge tables.

Also dont use Order by which overkills the query run time.

```
SELECT
      DISTINCT GROUP_DIST_NUMBER,
             BEGIN_DATE,
             PRICE_DROP_DATE
FROM
      (SELECT                       /*+ PARALLEL (P,4) PARALLEL (L,4)*/
            DISTINCT
            G.GROUP_DIST_NUMBER,
            TO_DATE ( :B2,
                    'DD-MON-YYYY' )
                BEGIN_DATE,
            TO_DATE ( :B2,
                    'DD-MON-YYYY' )
                PRICE_DROP_DATE
       FROM
            POS_DISTI_GROUP G,
            POS_CUST_XREF M,
            S_CPT_SEQ_NO C,
            PP_STD_PRICE P,
            S_CPT_AUDIT A,
            RPT_PRODUCT_VALUE_LEVEL L
       WHERE
                G.END_DATE > TO_DATE ( :B2,
                                  'DD-MON-YYYY' )
            AND G.GROUP_DIST_NUMBER = M.DIST_NUMBER
            AND M.SG_BILL_TO_CUST_NO = A.BILL_TO_CUST_NO
            AND A.START_DATE <= TO_DATE ( :B2,
                                    'DD-MON-YYYY' )
            AND A.END_DATE >= TO_DATE ( :B2,
                                   'DD-MON-YYYY' )
            AND L.PROD_VALUE = P.PROD_VALUE
            AND L.PROD_LEVEL = P.PROD_LEVEL
            AND C.CPT_PRICE_CODE IN
                    (SELECT                    /*+  PARALLEL (P1,4)*/
                          DISTINCT C1.CPT_PRICE_CODE
                    FROM
                          PP_STD_PRICE P1,
                          S_CPT_PRICE_CODE C1,
                          S_CPT_SEQ_NO S1
                    WHERE
                             P1.STDP_ID = :B1
                          AND C1.CPT_PRICE_CAT LIKE 'NB%'
                          AND C1.CPT_PRICE_CODE = S1.CPT_PRICE_CODE
                          AND S1.PRICE_PROTECTABLE = 'Y')
            AND C.CPT_PRICE_CODE = P.CUST_PRICE_TYPE
            AND P.STDP_ID = :B1
            AND A.CUST_PRICE_TYPE = C.CPT_BILL_CODE
            AND M.ACTIVE_IND != 'N'
            AND ( M.CATEGORY_TYPE LIKE 'DIRECT%'
                OR M.INDIRECT_DISTI = 'Y' )
            AND TRUNC ( M.ARCHIVE_DATE ) > TRUNC ( SYSDATE )
       UNION
       SELECT                      /*+  PARALLEL (P,4) PARALLEL (L,4) */
            G.GROUP_DIST_NUMBER,
            P.BEGIN_DATE,
            MIN ( INVT.PRICE_DROP_DATE ) PRICE_DROP_DATE
       FROM
            POS_DISTI_GROUP G,
            POS_CUST_XREF M,
            PP_DEBIT_AUTHORIZATION P,
            RPT_PRODUCT_VALUE_LEVEL L,
            POS_PP_INVENTORY PARTITION ("F2011_Q2") INVT
       WHERE
                G.END_DATE > TO_DATE ( :B2,
                                  'DD-MON-YYYY' )
            AND G.GROUP_DIST_NUMBER = M.DIST_NUMBER
            AND M.ACTIVE_IND != 'N'
            AND ( M.CATEGORY_TYPE LIKE 'DIRECT%'
                OR M.INDIRECT_DISTI = 'Y' )
            AND G.DIST_NUMBER = P.DIST_NUMBER
            AND L.PROD_VALUE = P.PROD_VALUE
            AND L.PROD_LEVEL = P.PROD_LEVEL
            AND P.BEGIN_DATE >= TO_DATE ( :B2,
                                    'DD-MON-YYYY' )
                            - 6
            AND P.BEGIN_DATE <= TO_DATE ( :B2,
                                    'DD-MON-YYYY' )
            AND INVT.DIST_NUMBER = G.GROUP_DIST_NUMBER
            AND INVT.STMODEL = L.MOD_DESC
            AND INVT.PPCF_SHOW_DATE = P.BEGIN_DATE
            AND P.PRICE_TYPE = 'I'
            AND ( P.POS_PROCESSED_FLAG IS NULL
                OR P.POS_PROCESSED_FLAG != 'C' )
            AND P.POS_PP_FLAG = 'Y'
            AND TRUNC ( M.ARCHIVE_DATE ) > TRUNC ( SYSDATE )
       GROUP BY
            G.GROUP_DIST_NUMBER,
            P.BEGIN_DATE);
```

**EXPLAIN PLAN**

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                         | Name                        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Pstart| Pstop |    TQ  |IN-OUT| PQ Distrib |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                                  |                             |   101 |  2525 |  8500  (17)|       |       |        |      |            |
|   1 |  PX COORDINATOR                                   |                             |       |       |            |       |       |        |      |            |
|   2 |   PX SEND QC (RANDOM)                             | :TQ10005                    |   101 |  2525 |  8500  (17)|       |       |  Q1,05 | P->S | QC (RAND)  |
|   3 |    VIEW                                           |                             |   101 |  2525 |  8500  (17)|       |       |  Q1,05 | PCWP |            |
|   4 |     SORT UNIQUE                                   |                             |   101 | 18291 |  8500  (82)|       |       |  Q1,05 | PCWP |            |
|   5 |      PX RECEIVE                                   |                             |       |       |            |       |       |  Q1,05 | PCWP |            |
|   6 |       PX SEND HASH                                | :TQ10004                    |       |       |            |       |       |  Q1,04 | P->P | HASH       |
|   7 |        BUFFER SORT                                |                             |   101 |  2525 |            |       |       |  Q1,04 | PCWP |            |
|   8 |         UNION-ALL                                 |                             |       |       |            |       |       |  Q1,04 | PCWP |            |
|   9 |          BUFFER SORT                              |                             |       |       |            |       |       |  Q1,04 | PCWC |            |
|  10 |           PX RECEIVE                              |                             |       |       |            |       |       |  Q1,04 | PCWP |            |
|  11 |            PX SEND ROUND-ROBIN                    | :TQ10001                    |       |       |            |       |       |        | S->P | RND-ROBIN  |
|  12 |             MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN                  |                             |    10M|  1737M|  1635   (5)|       |       |        |      |            |
|* 13 |              HASH JOIN                            |                             |  2439 |   419K|   322   (3)|       |       |        |      |            |
|* 14 |               TABLE ACCESS FULL                   | POS_DISTI_GROUP             |   100 |  1800 |     5   (0)|       |       |        |      |            |
|* 15 |               HASH JOIN                           |                             |  2452 |   378K|   317   (3)|       |       |        |      |            |
|* 16 |                TABLE ACCESS FULL                  | S_CPT_SEQ_NO                |   651 |  5208 |     5   (0)|       |       |        |      |            |
|  17 |                NESTED LOOPS                       |                             |   580 | 87000 |   311   (2)|       |       |        |      |            |
|  18 |                 NESTED LOOPS                      |                             |    34 |  4658 |   131   (4)|       |       |        |      |            |
|* 19 |                  HASH JOIN                        |                             |     1 |    97 |   109   (5)|       |       |        |      |            |
|* 20 |                   HASH JOIN                       |                             |     9 |   774 |   107   (5)|       |       |        |      |            |
|* 21 |                    HASH JOIN                      |                             |     2 |   146 |   101   (4)|       |       |        |      |            |
|* 22 |                     TABLE ACCESS FULL             | POS_CUST_XREF               |    54 |  2268 |    25   (4)|       |       |        |      |            |
|* 23 |                     TABLE ACCESS FULL             | S_CPT_AUDIT                 |    68 |  2108 |    76   (4)|       |       |        |      |            |
|  24 |                    TABLE ACCESS FULL              | S_CPT_SEQ_NO                |  1301 | 16913 |     5   (0)|       |       |        |      |            |
|* 25 |                   TABLE ACCESS FULL               | S_CPT_PRICE_CODE            |    21 |   231 |     2   (0)|       |       |        |      |            |
|* 26 |                  INDEX RANGE SCAN                 | UK_PP_STD_PRICE_STDP_ID     |    26 |  1040 |    22   (0)|       |       |        |      |            |
|* 27 |                 VIEW                              | RPT_PRODUCT_VALUE_LEVEL     |     1 |    13 |     5   (0)|       |       |        |      |            |
|  28 |                  UNION ALL PUSHED PREDICATE       |                             |       |       |            |       |       |        |      |            |
|  29 |                   NESTED LOOPS OUTER              |                             |     1 |    46 |     2   (0)|       |       |        |      |            |
|  30 |                    NESTED LOOPS OUTER             |                             |     1 |    42 |     2   (0)|       |       |        |      |            |
|  31 |                     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   | SMA_STMODEL                 |     1 |    28 |     2   (0)|       |       |        |      |            |
|* 32 |                      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN            | PK_SMA_STMODEL              |     1 |       |     1   (0)|       |       |        |      |            |
|* 33 |                     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN             | PK_SEAEGO_PRODUCT_HIERARCHY |   298 |  4172 |     0   (0)|       |       |        |      |            |
|* 34 |                    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN              | PK_S_CAP_GROUP              |     2 |     8 |     0   (0)|       |       |        |      |            |
|  35 |                   NESTED LOOPS OUTER              |                             |     1 |    77 |     2   (0)|       |       |        |      |            |
|  36 |                    NESTED LOOPS OUTER             |                             |     1 |    73 |     2   (0)|       |       |        |      |            |
|  37 |                     NESTED LOOPS                  |                             |     1 |    59 |     2   (0)|       |       |        |      |            |
|  38 |                      NESTED LOOPS OUTER           |                             |     1 |    31 |     2   (0)|       |       |        |      |            |
|  39 |                       NESTED LOOPS OUTER          |                             |     1 |    27 |     2   (0)|       |       |        |      |            |
|  40 |                        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| SMA_PRODUCTMODEL            |     1 |    23 |     2   (0)|       |       |        |      |            |
|* 41 |                         INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | PK_SMA_PRODUCTMODEL         |     1 |       |     1   (0)|       |       |        |      |            |
|* 42 |                        INDEX UNIQUE SCAN          | PK_S_FAMILY                 |  1366 |  5464 |     0   (0)|       |       |        |      |            |
|* 43 |                       INDEX UNIQUE SCAN           | PK_F_MODPRODMGR             |    22 |    88 |     0   (0)|       |       |        |      |            |
|  44 |                      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | SMA_STMODEL                 | 13965 |   381K|     1   (0)|       |       |        |      |            |
|* 45 |                       INDEX UNIQUE SCAN           | PK_SMA_STMODEL              |     1 |       |     0   (0)|       |       |        |      |            |
|* 46 |                     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN             | PK_SEAEGO_PRODUCT_HIERARCHY |   298 |  4172 |     0   (0)|       |       |        |      |            |
|* 47 |                    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN              | PK_S_CAP_GROUP              |     2 |     8 |     0   (0)|       |       |        |      |            |
|* 48 |                   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN               | IDX_RPT_PROD_MV_PROD_NO     |     1 |    12 |     1   (0)|       |       |        |      |            |
|  49 |              BUFFER SORT                          |                             |  4128 | 20640 |  1629   (5)|       |       |        |      |            |
|* 50 |               INDEX RANGE SCAN                    | UK_PP_STD_PRICE_STDP_ID     |  4128 | 20640 |    23   (0)|       |       |        |      |            |
|  51 |          HASH GROUP BY                            |                             |     1 |   191 |  5578   (2)|       |       |  Q1,04 | PCWP |            |
|  52 |           PX RECEIVE                              |                             |     1 |   191 |  5578   (2)|       |       |  Q1,04 | PCWP |            |
|  53 |            PX SEND HASH                           | :TQ10003                    |     1 |   191 |  5578   (2)|       |       |  Q1,03 | P->P | HASH       |
|  54 |             HASH GROUP BY                         |                             |     1 |   191 |  5578   (2)|       |       |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|* 55 |              FILTER                               |                             |       |       |            |       |       |  Q1,03 | PCWC |            |
|  56 |               NESTED LOOPS                        |                             |     1 |   191 |  5575   (2)|       |       |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|  57 |                NESTED LOOPS                       |                             |     7 |  1176 |  5562   (2)|       |       |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|* 58 |                 HASH JOIN                         |                             |    74 |  8584 |  1347   (3)|       |       |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|  59 |                  BUFFER SORT                      |                             |       |       |            |       |       |  Q1,03 | PCWC |            |
|  60 |                   PX RECEIVE                      |                             |    60 |  3780 |    31   (7)|       |       |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|  61 |                    PX SEND HASH                   | :TQ10000                    |    60 |  3780 |    31   (7)|       |       |        | S->P | HASH       |
|* 62 |                     HASH JOIN                     |                             |    60 |  3780 |    31   (7)|       |       |        |      |            |
|* 63 |                      TABLE ACCESS FULL            | POS_CUST_XREF               |    60 |  2100 |    25   (4)|       |       |        |      |            |
|* 64 |                      TABLE ACCESS FULL            | POS_DISTI_GROUP             |   100 |  2800 |     5   (0)|       |       |        |      |            |
|  65 |                  PX RECEIVE                       |                             |   345 | 18285 |  1316   (2)|       |       |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|  66 |                   PX SEND HASH                    | :TQ10002                    |   345 | 18285 |  1316   (2)|       |       |  Q1,02 | P->P | HASH       |
|  67 |                    PX BLOCK ITERATOR              |                             |   345 | 18285 |  1316   (2)|       |       |  Q1,02 | PCWC |            |
|* 68 |                     TABLE ACCESS FULL             | PP_DEBIT_AUTHORIZATION      |   345 | 18285 |  1316   (2)|       |       |  Q1,02 | PCWP |            |
|  69 |                 PARTITION RANGE ALL               |                             |     1 |    52 |   205   (1)|     1 |    33 |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|* 70 |                  INDEX RANGE SCAN                 | POS_PP_INVENTORY_PK         |     1 |    52 |   205   (1)|     1 |    33 |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|* 71 |                VIEW                               | RPT_PRODUCT_VALUE_LEVEL     |     1 |    23 |     7   (0)|       |       |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|  72 |                 UNION ALL PUSHED PREDICATE        |                             |       |       |            |       |       |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|* 73 |                  FILTER                           |                             |       |       |            |       |       |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|  74 |                   NESTED LOOPS OUTER              |                             |     1 |    46 |     2   (0)|       |       |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|  75 |                    NESTED LOOPS OUTER             |                             |     1 |    42 |     2   (0)|       |       |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|  76 |                     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   | SMA_STMODEL                 |     1 |    28 |     2   (0)|       |       |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|* 77 |                      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN            | PK_SMA_STMODEL              |     1 |       |     1   (0)|       |       |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|* 78 |                     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN             | PK_SEAEGO_PRODUCT_HIERARCHY |   298 |  4172 |     0   (0)|       |       |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|* 79 |                    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN              | PK_S_CAP_GROUP              |     2 |     8 |     0   (0)|       |       |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|  80 |                  NESTED LOOPS OUTER               |                             |     1 |    77 |     3   (0)|       |       |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|  81 |                   NESTED LOOPS OUTER              |                             |     1 |    73 |     3   (0)|       |       |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|  82 |                    NESTED LOOPS OUTER             |                             |     1 |    69 |     3   (0)|       |       |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|  83 |                     NESTED LOOPS OUTER            |                             |     1 |    65 |     3   (0)|       |       |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|  84 |                      NESTED LOOPS                 |                             |     1 |    51 |     3   (0)|       |       |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|* 85 |                       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | SMA_PRODUCTMODEL            |     1 |    23 |     2   (0)|       |       |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|* 86 |                        INDEX UNIQUE SCAN          | PK_SMA_PRODUCTMODEL         |     1 |       |     1   (0)|       |       |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|  87 |                       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | SMA_STMODEL                 |     1 |    28 |     1   (0)|       |       |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|* 88 |                        INDEX UNIQUE SCAN          | PK_SMA_STMODEL              |     1 |       |     0   (0)|       |       |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|* 89 |                      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN            | PK_SEAEGO_PRODUCT_HIERARCHY |   298 |  4172 |     0   (0)|       |       |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|* 90 |                     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN             | PK_S_FAMILY                 |  1366 |  5464 |     0   (0)|       |       |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|* 91 |                    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN              | PK_S_CAP_GROUP              |     2 |     8 |     0   (0)|       |       |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|* 92 |                   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN               | PK_F_MODPRODMGR             |    22 |    88 |     0   (0)|       |       |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|* 93 |                  MAT_VIEW ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   | RPT_PROD_MV                 |     1 |    24 |     2   (0)|       |       |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|* 94 |                   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN               | IDX_RPT_PROD_MV_PROD_NO     |     1 |       |     1   (0)|       |       |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

  13 - access("G"."GROUP_DIST_NUMBER"="M"."DIST_NUMBER")
  14 - filter("G"."END_DATE">TO_DATE(:B2,'DD-MON-YYYY'))
  15 - access("C1"."CPT_PRICE_CODE"="S1"."CPT_PRICE_CODE")
  16 - filter("S1"."PRICE_PROTECTABLE"='Y')
  19 - access("C"."CPT_PRICE_CODE"="C1"."CPT_PRICE_CODE")
  20 - access("A"."CUST_PRICE_TYPE"="C"."CPT_BILL_CODE")
  21 - access("M"."SG_BILL_TO_CUST_NO"="A"."BILL_TO_CUST_NO")
  22 - filter("M"."SG_BILL_TO_CUST_NO" IS NOT NULL AND ("M"."INDIRECT_DISTI"='Y' OR "M"."CATEGORY_TYPE" LIKE 'DIRECT%') AND "M"."ACTIVE_IND"<>'N' AND 
              TRUNC(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("M"."ARCHIVE_DATE"))>TRUNC(SYSDATE@!))
  23 - filter("A"."START_DATE"<=TO_DATE(:B2,'DD-MON-YYYY') AND "A"."END_DATE">=TO_DATE(:B2,'DD-MON-YYYY'))
  25 - filter("C1"."CPT_PRICE_CAT" LIKE 'NB%')
  26 - access("P"."STDP_ID"=TO_NUMBER(:B1) AND "C"."CPT_PRICE_CODE"="P"."CUST_PRICE_TYPE")
       filter("C"."CPT_PRICE_CODE"="P"."CUST_PRICE_TYPE")
  27 - filter("L"."PROD_LEVEL"="P"."PROD_LEVEL")
  32 - access("ST"."MOD_DESC"="P"."PROD_VALUE")
  33 - access("ST"."MARKETING_NAME"="PH"."MARKETING_NAME"(+))
  34 - access("ST"."MOD_CAPACITY_FORMATTED"="SCG"."MOD_CAPACITY_FORMATTED"(+))
  41 - access("PM"."MODEL"="P"."PROD_VALUE")
  42 - access("SF"."FAMILY"(+)=SUBSTRB("PM"."MODEL",1,3))
  43 - access("PM"."DESIGN_APPLICATION"="DA"."DESIGN_APPLICATION"(+))
  45 - access("PM"."MOD_DESC"="ST"."MOD_DESC")
  46 - access("ST"."MARKETING_NAME"="PH"."MARKETING_NAME"(+))
  47 - access("ST"."MOD_CAPACITY_FORMATTED"="SCG"."MOD_CAPACITY_FORMATTED"(+))
  48 - access("PROD_NO"="P"."PROD_VALUE")
  50 - access("P1"."STDP_ID"=TO_NUMBER(:B1))
  55 - filter(TO_DATE(:B2,'DD-MON-YYYY')-6<=TO_DATE(:B2,'DD-MON-YYYY'))
  58 - access("G"."DIST_NUMBER"="P"."DIST_NUMBER")
  62 - access("G"."GROUP_DIST_NUMBER"="M"."DIST_NUMBER")
  63 - filter(("M"."INDIRECT_DISTI"='Y' OR "M"."CATEGORY_TYPE" LIKE 'DIRECT%') AND "M"."ACTIVE_IND"<>'N' AND 
              TRUNC(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("M"."ARCHIVE_DATE"))>TRUNC(SYSDATE@!))
  64 - filter("G"."END_DATE">TO_DATE(:B2,'DD-MON-YYYY'))
  68 - filter("P"."PRICE_TYPE"='I' AND "P"."POS_PP_FLAG"='Y' AND ("P"."POS_PROCESSED_FLAG"<>'C' OR "P"."POS_PROCESSED_FLAG" IS NULL) AND 
              "P"."BEGIN_DATE"<=TO_DATE(:B2,'DD-MON-YYYY') AND "P"."BEGIN_DATE">=TO_DATE(:B2,'DD-MON-YYYY')-6)
  70 - access("INVT"."DIST_NUMBER"="G"."GROUP_DIST_NUMBER" AND "INVT"."PPCF_SHOW_DATE"="P"."BEGIN_DATE")
       filter("INVT"."PPCF_SHOW_DATE"<=TO_DATE(:B2,'DD-MON-YYYY') AND "INVT"."PPCF_SHOW_DATE">=TO_DATE(:B2,'DD-MON-YYYY')-6 AND 
              "INVT"."PPCF_SHOW_DATE"="P"."BEGIN_DATE")
  71 - filter("L"."PROD_LEVEL"="P"."PROD_LEVEL")
  73 - filter("P"."PROD_VALUE"="INVT"."STMODEL")
  77 - access("ST"."MOD_DESC"="P"."PROD_VALUE")
  78 - access("ST"."MARKETING_NAME"="PH"."MARKETING_NAME"(+))
  79 - access("ST"."MOD_CAPACITY_FORMATTED"="SCG"."MOD_CAPACITY_FORMATTED"(+))
  85 - filter("PM"."MOD_DESC"="INVT"."STMODEL")
  86 - access("PM"."MODEL"="P"."PROD_VALUE")
  88 - access("ST"."MOD_DESC"="INVT"."STMODEL")
  89 - access("ST"."MARKETING_NAME"="PH"."MARKETING_NAME"(+))
  90 - access("SF"."FAMILY"(+)=SUBSTRB("PM"."MODEL",1,3))
  91 - access("ST"."MOD_CAPACITY_FORMATTED"="SCG"."MOD_CAPACITY_FORMATTED"(+))
  92 - access("PM"."DESIGN_APPLICATION"="DA"."DESIGN_APPLICATION"(+))
  93 - filter("MOD_DESC"="INVT"."STMODEL")
  94 - access("PROD_NO"="P"."PROD_VALUE")

Note
-----
   - 'PLAN_TABLE' is old version
```

**PS:**
Did you manage to get Run time? Also I change the query, please test this and let us know the result. Ideally the first query should be faster than yours and the second one (replaced the first) should be better than the first one.Remember to keep them separately with notes on performance.

Comment: still searching how to get the run time without run that query

Comment: You need to run that query... Forget about the first one try the second one. But remember you need to pass relative dates as per the partition.

Comment: If you get incorrect data, then use correct partition names to look for. also try to select your view separately to see how much time it takes

Comment: i try to run that query and got this message
ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P007
ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace TEMP
12801. 00000 -  "error signaled in parallel query server %s"
*Cause:    A parallel query server reached an exception condition.
*Action:   Check the following error message for the cause, and consult
           your error manual for the appropriate action.
*Comment:  This error can be turned off with event 10397, in which
           case the server's actual error is signaled instead.

Comment: It means too many Parallels. Remove the parallel from view or alter session set sort_area_size = 1,048,576,000; -- 1 Gig

Comment: mean i need to remove PARALLEL (L,4) right?
will post the result tomorrow, btw, thanks @realspirituals

Comment: Yes. remove them to have optmized. Also check you can increase sort area size

Comment: i cannot increase sort area size and still got same error 
ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P005
ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace TEMP
12801. 00000 -  "error signaled in parallel query server %s"
*Cause:    A parallel query server reached an exception condition.
*Action:   Check the following error message for the cause, and consult
           your error manual for the appropriate action.
*Comment:  This error can be turned off with event 10397, in which
           case the server's actual error is signaled instead.

Comment: reduce the usage of parallel and you cant do much.

Comment: i try to run your query above in production (before this in staging) and the result it take 3 hour and 8 minutes to complete, after try switch off/on suggest by @Galbarad, problem with long execution is on 2nd WHERE statement

Comment: Changing the degree of parallelism does not have any direct, significant impact on the amount of temporary tablespace required.  In general, if you ask for twice as many parallel servers each one will use half as much temporary tablespace.  Changing sort_area_size won't help either, that's just the amount of memory before it starts to use temporary tablespace.  Although there are so many variables involved with these plans it's hard to say what indirect affects DOP changes will have to the resource requirements.